# What's the correct syntax to filter the MIDDLE DOT Unicode character using a Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax to filter the [`MIDDLE DOT`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b7/index.htm) Unicode character (`U+00B7`) out of a string and keep the original string

```
     $_ =~ s/test_of_character (.*[^\x{00b7}])/$1/gi;
```

From the code above, I'm not sure how to keep the original string before removing the middle dot from the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Perl and Unicode, you should read the manuals such as:

- [Perl Unicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html)
- [Perl Unicode Introduction](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro.html)
- [Perl Unicode Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html)

The first of those shows that you can write a Unicode code point such as U+00B7 using the notation:

```
\N{U+00B7}
```

You can also use the Unicode character name:

```
\N{MIDDLE DOT}
```

The rest is basic [regex](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) handling.  If you need to keep the original string, then you can use the `/r`modifier for the regex if your Perl is modern enough (added to [Perl 5.14.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Regular-Expressions)). Alternatively (for older versions of Perl), you can copy the string and edit the copy, as with `$altans` below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'unicode_strings';
use utf8;

binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

my $string = "This is some text with a ·•· middle dot or four \N{U+00B7}\N{MIDDLE DOT} in it";

print "string = $string\n";

my $answer = ($string =~ s/\N{MIDDLE DOT}//gr);
my $altans;

($altans = $string) =~ s/\N{U+00B7}//g;

# Fix grammar!
$answer =~ s/\ba\b/no/;
$answer =~ s/ or four //;

print "string = $string\n";
print "answer = $answer\n";
print "altans = $altans\n";
```

Output:

```
string = This is some text with a ·•· middle dot or four ·· in it
string = This is some text with a ·•· middle dot or four ·· in it
answer = This is some text with no • middle dot in it
altans = This is some text with a • middle dot or four  in it
```

Note that the 'big middle dot' is U+2022, BULLET.

---

[ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) points out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307354/whats-the-correct-syntax-to-filter-the-middle-dot-unicode-character-using-a-per/20307560?noredirect=1#comment30304560_20307560):

> Note that `\x{00B7}` and `\xB7` would match the same character as `\N{U+00B7}`.

And indeed, that is the case, as this extension of the code above shows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'unicode_strings';
use utf8;

binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

my $string = "This is some text with a ·•· middle dot or four \N{U+00B7}\N{MIDDLE DOT} in it";

print "string = $string\n";

my $answer = ($string =~ s/\N{MIDDLE DOT}//gr);
my $altans;

($altans = $string) =~ s/\N{U+00B7}//g;

# Fix grammar!
$answer =~ s/\ba\b/no/;
$answer =~ s/ or four //;

print "string = $string\n";
print "answer = $answer\n";
print "altans = $altans\n";

my $extan1 = $string;
$extan1 =~ s/\xB7//g;
print "extan1 = $extan1\n";

my $extan2 = $string;
$extan2 =~ s/\x{00B7}//g;
$extan2 =~ s/\x{0065}//g;
$extan2 =~ s/\x{2022}//g;
print "extan2 = $extan2\n";
```

With the output:

```
string = This is some text with a ·•· middle dot or four ·· in it
string = This is some text with a ·•· middle dot or four ·· in it
answer = This is some text with no • middle dot in it
altans = This is some text with a • middle dot or four  in it
extan1 = This is some text with a • middle dot or four  in it
extan2 = This is som txt with a  middl dot or four  in it
```

This is Perl: TMTOWTDI — There's More Than One Way To Do It!

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the needed educational explanation along with the resolution.

Comment: Note that `\x{00B7}` and `\xB7` would match the same character as `\N{U+00B7}`.

Comment: @ikegami: interesting — answer updated to take your comment into account.  Thanks!

Comment: Where does "\N{U+00B7}" come from? I can't find any documentation for that syntax other than a vague "\N{U+...}" in perlunicode.

Comment: It comes from the vague `\N{U+…}` in [Perl Unicode](), [Perl Regex Ref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref#ESCAPE-SEQUENCES).  I too can't find much more about these escape sequences in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

To remove *all* Unicode `MIDDLE DOT` characters from the string, you can write

```
s/\N{MIDDLE DOT}//g
```

or

```
tr/\N{MIDDLE DOT}//d
```

I'm not clear what you mean by *"keep the original string"*, but if you want to leave `$_` unchanged and remove `MIDDLE DOT` characters from a copy of it then you can write

```
(my $modified = $_) =~ s/\N{MIDDLE DOT}//g
```

or

```
my $modified = s/\N{MIDDLE DOT}//gr
```

Answer (score 0):

This, a general answer using your own regex, slightly modified

`$_ =~ s/([^\x{00b7}]*+)\x{00b7}+/$1/g;`

The inverse ( *preferred* ) equivalent is

`$_ =~ s/\x{00b7}+//g;`